# Custom chrome extension shortcuts not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shortcut

I am creating my own chrome extension. I would like to be able to run a script after clicking a shortcut. My manifest looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Test ext",
    "homepage_url": "",
    "icons": {
      "16": "icons/test-icon.jpg",
      "48": "icons/test-icon.jpg",
      "128": "icons/test-icon.jpg"
    },
    "default_locale": "en",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["src/bg/background.js"],
      "persistent": true
    },
    "commands":{
      "run-script": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+E",
          "windows": "Ctrl+E",
          "mac": "Command+E"
        },
        "description": "Run",
        "global": true
      }
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/test-icon.jpg",
      "default_title": "browser action demo",
      "default_popup": "src/browser_action/browser_action.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "https://*/*", "storage"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "https://www.test.co.uk/*"
        ],
        "js": ["src/inject/inject.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

So I have extension with simple UI and start button. I would like to be able to use CTRL+E or CMD+E to run a script after that. When I go to extensions in chrome settings I see shortcut:

[image]

So as I understand I should get `console.log` and I am getting it in the background console. But what if I would like to use that shortcut for changing actual page to another? How can I achieve that? This is not working:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  location.replace(
    `https://www.solebox.com/en_GB/checkout?stage=shipping#shipping`
  );
});
```

Nothing is happening.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed by just making:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  chrome.tabs.update({
    url: `https://www.google.com`,
  });
});
```

As I understand I cannot use `location.replace` or any other js methods in `background.js`. I have to use only chrome commands to switch page and then use my `inject.js` file to make some changes on a page.

Answer (score 3):

// background.js

```js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  // location.replace(...)
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: 'https://...'});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+E` is an shortcut registerd by chrome itself, maybe try `Ctrl+Q`.

It is also important that you open the console of the service worker/background script, the log would show up here.

[image: Chrome extension view]

Comment: this time I got this error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCommand' of undefined' where should I place this part for adding listener to command?

Comment: I want to have an extension where I can use command anytime I am on a page that extension supports and I want to make something after clicking that command for example go to www.google.com after

Comment: this should be in your background,js